# AVAudioPlayerNode skips a lot of sounds when stopped and started again

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm scheduling a buffer periodically using `scheduleBuffer` function. The completion handler schedules the next sound when current one is done, like so:

```swift
func scheduleSounds() {
    if !isPlaying { return }
   
    while beatsScheduled < beatsToScheduleAhead {
        // Returns AVAudioTime of the next sound, based on sample time
        // first sound is always sample time 0, then increments.
        let nextTime = getNextTime()

        player.scheduleBuffer(
            soundBuffer,
            at: nextTime,
            options: AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferOptions(rawValue: 0),
            completionHandler: {
                self.queue!.sync {
                    print("Finished playing a sound!")
                    scheduleSounds()
                }
            }
        )

        beatsScheduled += 1

        if !playerStarted {
            player.play(at: nil)
            playerStarted = true
        }
    }
}
```

When I stop and then start the player/engine there is a delay before the sound starts playing and after logging which sounds play when I noticed that there are couple of sounds that the engine does not play. **My suspicion is that the player nodes think that the sample time has already passed relative to the player node time.** I think I might not be resetting or stopping something properly, here's how I start and stop the sounds:

```swift
func start() {
    do {
        try engine.start()

        isPlaying = true

        queue!.sync() {
            self.scheduleSounds()
        }
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}

func stop() {
    isPlaying = false
        
    player.stop()
    engine.stop()
        
    playerStarted = false
}
```

So the problem is how do I make sure that there are no sounds that AVAudioPlayerNode skips before playing the sound?

Comment: Do you need to stop in the 1st place? Perhaps pause would be enough.

Comment: The audio hardware does not stop when you just pause, and I want to make the app as energy-efficient as possible. Additionally, I don't really want to avoid fixing the bug just because I can, I'd rather figure out what exactly is wrong here so that no other bugs resurface later on.

Comment: Did you ensure to configure the node's output format with the same number of channels as are in the files and buffers to be played? Otherwise, channels will be dropped or added as required. It's usually preferable to use an AVAudioMixerNode to do this configuration.

Comment: @AISHWARYAM Yes, the player nodes are attached to the mixer and mixer is attached to the output node.

Comment: pausing both player and engine would work better I think